# Subscription sample using websockets or IPC?

Tags: json-rpc, events, nodejs, ipc

So I was using the web3 API from the NodeJS 'web3' module very happily and it works very well (it uses HTTP transport AFAIU). But now I want to receive events from the server (without polling), and for that it seems I need to use the [subscription API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB).

However, the documentation I just linked states **subscriptions require a full duplex connection. Geth offers such connections in the form of websockets (enable with --ws) and ipc (enabled by default)**. Fair enough.

But, for the life of me, I cannot find any sample out there of how to connect via IPC/WebSockets. If the documentation included a simple hello world sample of a subscription, it would be rad.

Comment: I didn't try but web3 ipc seems to be what you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3_ipc

Answer (score 1):

hacking around I connected in python this way, pretty simple:

```
➜  ~ ipython2
Python 2.7.11+ (default, May  9 2016, 15:54:33)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import socket

In [3]: s=socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

In [4]: s.connect("/home/XXX/.ethereum/geth.ipc")

In [5]: message = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":1}'

In [6]: s.send(message)
Out[6]: 60

In [7]: s.recv(1024)
Out[7]: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeededededede"}\n'
```

still browsing it seems this [library](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-ipc-client) is designed to do exactly what you want, but in python

Answer (score 1):

you can also use netcat :

```
➜  ~  nc -U /home/XXX/.ethereum/geth.ipc
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeededededede"}
```

Comment: how about using nodejs? :) (if you provide js sample that I'll upvote all your 3 answers :) )

Comment: i'm sorry I don't know js libraries well enough for that but I'm pretty sure other will find a way ;)

Comment: @knocte, bribing him?  Did you find js sample? if you send me I'll upvote your answers  ;)

Answer (score 1):

web3 has providers for IPC and Websockets

http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#providers

You can use it simply with

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider(/path/to/.ipc, net))
```